# Copy resource and configs to IIS directory instead of binary in Visual Studio

Tags: wcf, resources, directory, copy, config

I've face a problem when WCF service using a lot of mobules copies resource and config files to binary directory. But I need them to be copied to IIS directory.
Can anyone please advice is there any Visual Studio setting for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you're asking how to change the build output to go to a specified directory.  If that's the case, you can do this in the Properties pages of the project.   Right-click on the project, and select Properties.

Select the Build tab, and under Output you'll see a place to set the output path (Output path).

If this isn't what you're asking, can you clarify your question?

Comment: it almost what I've wanded. But hot to change build directory only for config files, and leave libraries unchanged?